# expect: how to send an EOF to spawnd process

Tags: tcl, expect

I have a program read from stdin and process it. ( like "tee /some/file" )

This program wait stdin end to exit itself.

If I spawn it from `Expect`, after I `send` many content, how to send an "EOF" to the program?

there is a `close` command in Expect, but it will also send a SIGHUP, and can not `expect` program output anymore.

Comment: I'd think that `send \x04` would do. That sends a Ctrl+D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expect works (on non-Windows) by using a virtual terminal which the spawned program runs within. This means that you can do things by sending character sequences to simulate keys. In particular, the [EOF control sequence is done with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts#Command_line_shortcuts), which becomes the character U+000004. The terminal processes this to turn it into a true EOF.

There's a few ways to write it, depending on which escape sequence you prefer, but one of these will work:

```
# Hexadecimal-encoded escape
send \x04
```

```
# Octal-encoded escape
send \004
```

```
# UNICODE escape (also hexadecimal)
send \u0004
```

```
# Generate by a command
send [format "%c" 4]
```

When Expect is using Tcl 8.6, these all generate the same bytecode so use whichever you prefer.

Comment: It can be changed with `stty eof ^Z` for instance do you know how to query it and thus avoid hardcoding ?